# All my eclipse files are displaying as .DATAWAIT

Tags: eclipse

Till yesterday it worked fine, today morning when started machine it showing short cut itself wrong and all my files are displaying as .DATAWAITFILE.

Please help me?

Comment: Can you include more data? Eclipse version, operating system, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've been infected by a ransomware.

See: https://pcthreatskiller.com/remove-datawait-file-virus

(Datawait is a new type of ransomware. No solution has yet been found to decrypt your files. Hope you have a backup of your files.)